# Android how to install older API versions?

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse my Android SDK Manager doesn't show as far back as API level 7 which is what I would like to install.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you check if the option "Show: Updates/New" is checked in the SDK Manager? If this is not checked, it will not show you any new packages (or the ones that you have not yet installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of the Android SDK are available at http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html

Answer (score 2):

I was having a problem with this also. I tried the other answer here and nothing worked. I went into Tools/Options (in the Android SDK Manager) and checked "Force https:// sources to be fetched using http://" and reloaded and the older APIs magically appeared.