# How to install older versions of Android via the SDK Manager?

Tags: android

I downloaded the Android SDK from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), as suggested by all tutorials.

I downloaded Android v4.0.3 (API 15) via the SDK manager, but it won't allow me to download older SDK/API versions, e.g 2.2?

I found [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278534/android-how-to-install-older-api-versions), but when i try and download one of the packages, it just 404s.

I have a single repository setup in the SDK Manager:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My SDK manager shows that it is using

> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

for back versions of the SDK. Make sure you have the latest version of the Android tools (it's up to 20 as of a few days ago).

Comment: Bizarre. When i try to add that, it says "Error: This site is already listed". I tried deleting my other one, and it still has the error. Something is badly wrong, most likely with my installation..

Comment: i have v19 of tools...upgrading now to 20 see if it helps.

Comment: updating the tools did the trick (older versions are now visible). that's not very user friendly at all. and i couldnt find ANYTHING on google about installing older versions. anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

So you can't check the boxes next to the other api versions ?

In the Android SDK Manager you should be able to download it. 
For 2.2 that is api 8, so you would check the folder or just the sdk platform for api 8 and install.

Comment: i dont have rep to post image... but yeah, i can't even see the checkbox there. Tools, Android 4.0.3 (API 15), API 13, API 10, API 8. Under API 8 there is only "Dual Screen APIs", "Real3D" and "GALAXY Tab". Where is the "SDK Platform" checkbox under API 8?

Comment: Check the tools > Manage add on sites > and Google and Android systems are check.

Answer (score 0):

Download the lastest version of SDK manager by using Eclipse Help->Check for updates. Once the sdk manager is updated, it will show all the older sdks