# My SDK only shows the API level 17. how to add API level 14

Tags: android

This is my SDK Manager. I want to add API Level 14. how can i get it.
[image]

Comment: update your adtbundle and sdk platform tools then you will see the full list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287593/how-to-install-older-versions-of-android-via-the-sdk-manager

Comment: Also check "Obsolete"